No open HTTP ports detected when deploying Laravel project on Render using Docker
I'm deploying a Laravel application on Render using Docker, which includes nginx and MySQL services. Locally, everything works fine, but when I try to deploy on Render, I encounter this error:
Error
No open HTTP ports detected on 0.0.0.0, continuing to scan...
Port scan timeout reached, no open HTTP ports detected. If you don't need to receive public HTTP traffic, create a private service instead.
Timed out: Port scan timeout reached, no open HTTP ports detected. If you don't need to receive public HTTP traffic, create a private service instead.
Ngnix ports on composer file
ports:
- 89:80
- 447:443
not get any solution from the community yet.

I have a similar issue on Docker/gRPC/Rust, the service builds successfully when the pot is bind to 10000 which is like the preset for Render but fails if I use a custom port.
But even at that, I'm unable to access the service

I found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgzKoVIwHDY I hope it solve it
